# R Shiny - sankey plot with click events

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dom-events, googlevis

I'm trying to create an **R** shiny dashboard with a Sankey plot. I want to be able to extract the name of the clicked node.

There are two libraries that can plot Sankey diagrams, `networkD3` and `googleVis`. `networkD3` does allow you to monitor click events, even though another type of plot implemented in the same library comes with such feature (`forceNetwork()`).

`googleVis` package however has a function `gvisSankey` that can create sankey plots and as an option you can pass a parameter `gvis.listener.jscode` that should be able to capture it.

I'm afraid I'm not that familiar with JS and I'm struggling to get what I'm looking for. This is how far I managed to get:

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

datSK <- data.frame(From=c(rep("A",3), rep("B", 3)),
                    To=c(rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"),2)),
                    Weight=c(5,7,6,2,9,4))

SERVER <- function(input, output, session){
  sankey_click <- sprintf("var text = chart.getSelection();
 Shiny.onInputChange('%s', text.toString())", session$ns('text'))
  output$sankey <- renderGvis(
    gvisSankey(datSK, from="From", to="To", weight="Weight",
               options=list(gvis.listener.jscode = sankey_click, 
                            sankey = "{node: {interactivity: true, width: 50}}"))
  )
  
  click_event <- reactive({input$text})
  output$click <- renderText(click_event())
  
}

UI <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(12, htmlOutput("sankey"))),
  fluidRow(column(12, verbatimTextOutput("click")))  
)

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = SERVER)
```

As you can see, all I get is `object Object`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll share some details on how I debugged this since you are new to JavaScript and it can hopefully help you in the future.

First, I added a console.log statement to sankey_click to see what kind of object we were dealing with.  In Chrome, you can open the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

```
  sankey_click <- sprintf("var text = chart.getSelection();
 Shiny.onInputChange('%s', text.toString()); console.log(text);", session$ns('text'))
```

[image]

So, now we can see why you were returning an object.  The click is, in fact, returning an array of objects, each with a property 'name'.  Then, it is an easy fix once you know this.  Simply change sankey_click

```
  sankey_click <- sprintf("var text = chart.getSelection()[0]['name'];
 Shiny.onInputChange('%s', text.toString()); console.log(text);", session$ns('text'))
```

[image]

and when you're satisfied, remove the console.log

```
  sankey_click <- sprintf("var text = chart.getSelection()[0]['name'];
 Shiny.onInputChange('%s', text.toString());", session$ns('text'))
```

Just one way to deal with the Shiny Javascript when you don't know what is going on.

Comment: I'd give you a 100 upvotes for this answer if I could, thank you! You didn't just give me the answer, you showed me how to resolve similar issues in the future.